# py2app SyntaxError when running with python3.3

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, py2app

I have written a sudoku solver using especially, but not only, tkinter and multiprocessing. I want to make it a standalone app, which I'm using py2app for.

I've run py2applet-3.3 --make-setup sudoku_app.py (that is what it's called when installed through macports), and it succeeded at that. However when building with python3.3 (python3.3 setup.py py2app), it returns a SyntaxError with an almost endless stack trace that ends like this:

```
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 954, in load_module
co = compile(contents, pathname, 'exec', 0, True)
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sympy/mpmath/libmp/exec_py2.py", line 2
exec string in globals, locals
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When running the same setup file with python2.7, it does succeed to build, but there's a bunch of errors when trying to run the created .app. I've written my code in python3, although trying to maintain python2 compatibility through various try ... except - blocks and from **future** imports. At some point though, it got too complicated and I decided to just go with python3.

Why does py2app not work with python3 there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application doesn’t work with py2app (yet) because I didn’t consider the way you do py3k support. In particular, modulegraph assumes that all modules in the dependency graph contain valid python code for the current python version.

Could you file a bug at my bitbucket page (https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app) to ensure that I don’t forget to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I sure will. I've been able to 'fix' it myself by renaming the files in the stack trace: renamed exec_py2.py to _exec_py2.py and exec_py3.py to exec_py2.py. Maybe py2app just uses the wrong file?

Comment: Not really. The compatility layer probably contains something like “if Py3K: import exec_py3; else import exec_py2” and py2app (or rather modulegraph) looks at both imports even though only one can be reached.